# Measurable Partitions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I was wondering in the definition of the Measurable Partition what does the notation ; $\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty P_n $ means? We say that $P$ is a measurable partition if there exist some measurable set $M_0 \subset M$ with full measure such that, restricted to $M_0$, 
$$p=\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty P_n$$
for some increasing sequence $p_1 \prec p_2 ... \prec p_n\prec ... $ of countable partitions. By $p_i \prec p_{i+1}$ we mean that every element of $p_{i+1}$ is contained in some elements of $p_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you are reading Foundations of Ergodic Theory, I suppose the book written by Viana and Oliveira. The definition of measurable partition you give is on page 146 of the english version of the book (147 of the Portuguese version available online). Immediately after that definition, the authors define the notation 
$$ \bigvee_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{P}_n$$

"Represent by $\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{P}_n$ the partition whose elements are the non-empty intersections of the form $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty {P}_n$ with $P_n\in \mathcal{P}_n$ for every $n$. Equivalently, this is the coarser partition such that 
$$\mathcal{P}_n \prec \bigvee_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{P}_n $$
for every $n$"

The symbol $\prec$ is defined in the previous paragraph: "By $\mathcal{P_i}\prec\mathcal{P}_{i+1}$ we mean that every element of $\mathcal{P}_{i+1}$ is contained in some element of $\mathcal{P}_{i}$."

Comment: Yes that's the book that I mentioned. Thanks for your help. Actually I have trouble with two of the exercises of this section (Ergodic decomposition). one of them is related to the topic we just discussed. page 161 The exercise 5.2.3... I was thinking to use Lemma 5.2.1 but I have no idea what is the use of the assumption union of partitions generates the sigma-algebra? I would be more than happy if you can help me on this.

Comment: @Shahriar Your prerogative, but I found it peculiar that you accepted an answer saying the same as mine and given after. Hope you solve the matters with conditional expectations.

Comment: @Jonas I am greatly thankful for your answer to this question. I was not quite sure that we using this definition for the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't denote a measurable partition. Instead $\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty P_n$ denotes the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all intersections $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with $A_n\in P_n$ for each $n$.

However, in **Rokhlin's** notion of a measurable partition, the notation $\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty P_n$ denotes the collection of all sets of the form $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with $A_n\in P_n$ for each $n$.

In order to understand the difference between the two take the collection of stable invariant manifolds in a well-behaved system. Often this is an uncountable partition unlike in the "usual" notion of a measurable partition. In many situations this is a measurable partition in the sense of Rokhlin.

Comment: I mean how it is related to the definition of measurable partition that I just wrote above?

Comment: What you wrote is not the definition of a measurable partition. Please edit your question so that it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: It is exactly the definition which the book Foundations of Ergodic Theory uses for Ergodic decomposition and proof of Rokhlin disintegration Theorem.

Comment: I see, then you are using Rokhlin's notion of measurable partitions. More often it is used in the sense that it is simply a decomposition of the space into measurable sets (sometimes of positive measure). I have rephrased my answer